# docker, mariadb doesn't start at "init", based in debian:stable

Tags: docker, dockerfile

i am trying write a Dockerfile like that

```
FROM debian:stable
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y mariadb-server
EXPOSE 3306
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

I create the image with

```
docker build -t debian1 .
```

And i create the container with

```
docker run -d --name my_container_debian -i -t debian1
```

20 seconds after, docker ps -a tells that container is exited. Why? I want the container is up and mariadb running. Thanks. Sorry for the question.

Comment: Does `mysqld` run in foreground or background? It should be executed in foreground, otherwise, the container will just be ended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqld` alone would exit too soon.

If you look at a [MySQL server Dockerfile](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/blob/mysql-server/8.0/Dockerfile), you will note its `ENTRYPOINT` is a script [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/blob/mysql-server/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh) which will exec mysqld in foreground.

```
exec "$@"
```